# Jerus10 font metric (TFM) file not found after installing TexLive 2013

Tags: fonts, texlive, ubuntu, hebrew

I'll start by saying I'm new to ubuntu and texlive.

I just installed texlive2013 and am trying to create a pdf on ubuntu 12.04 TLS.

I'm using both English and Hebrew, but neither seam to work: when trying to create the PDF I get the (apparently known) message:

```
Font LHE/cmr/m/n/10=jerus10 at 10.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found
```

I've already installed `texlive-fonts-recommended`, but it doesn't seem to help.

I'm thinking that although the fonts are installed, there might be a problem getting their path.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to fixing this problem or understanding its cause?

---

TeX MWE:

```
%% LyX 2.0.2 created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
\documentclass[english,hebrew]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{english}%
hello\selectlanguage{hebrew}%
\end{document}
```

Comment: Well-written post with examples. As noted in your question [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/148961/hebrew-letters-in-a-math-equation) the problem is not with the .lyx or the .tex. It is with your TeX distribution and OS (I added the tag "ubuntu" for you). You might not want to go to the trouble, but if you reinstall a fresh Ubuntu, use [install-tl-ubuntu --hebrew](https://github.com/scottkosty/install-tl-ubuntu) and [upgrade to the newest stable version of LyX](http://wiki.lyx.org/LyX/LyXOnUbuntu#toc3) you will be able to compile the Hebrew docs you have posted.

Comment: So, did you try any of the suggestions below? Did it work? Did you do something else instead?

Comment: @einpoklum no, actually I wasn't able to do it, not even on ubuntu 12.04 (which I'm using now permanently). I just gave up after too many hours were wasted.

Comment: @user2190298: Would you mind commenting on the two answers, saying where things went wrong exactly?

Answer (score 2):

The part of [install-tl-ubuntu](https://github.com/scottkosty/install-tl-ubuntu) that is used for adding support for Hebrew is the following (I edited it so that it has a chance of working stand alone). I do not know if it will work for you or not without the rest of the script.

```
dTEXMFLOCAL="$(kpsewhich -var-value TEXMFLOCAL)"
WGET_CMD="wget --tries=5"
mkdir "/tmp/HebrewFonts" &&
cd "/tmp/HebrewFonts" &&
${WGET_CMD} "http://archive.debian.org/debian/pool/main/i/ivritex/ivritex_1.1.1-6_all.deb" &&
ar x "ivritex_1.1.1-6_all.deb" && tar -xf "data.tar.gz" &&
rsync -a "usr/share/texmf/" "${dTEXMFLOCAL}"
mktexlsr "${dTEXMFLOCAL}"
```

Comment: Hi scott. Since my last post (still on Windows) I've installed Ubuntu and thought the two problems weren't related. As for the lines above - how do I run that?

Comment: @user2190298 To run the code (which I cannot say will work because it is taken from a larger script), put it in a text file, say `installHebFonts.sh`, and run `sudo bash installHebFonts.sh`

Comment: You would at least need to run sudo mktexlsr "${dTEXMFLOCAL}" to update TeX's database of files. If this installs new fonts, you would also need to run updmap-sys or updmap to enable the map file as well. (I have no idea how Ubuntu's TeX packages handle this stuff - only how TeX Live would do it. So use at your own risk.)

Comment: I've tried installing tl again using 'install-tl-ubuntu --hebrew' and I've installed Lyx again. Now I can create PDFs, but hebrew in math formulas produces "Latex Error: Command \hebgimel unavailable in encoding T1". I've tried changing the font but the "use non-Tex fonts (via XeTeX\LuaTex)" box is locked so I can't tick it. Does this make sense somehow?

Comment: The errors with pdftex are normal (in the sense that I have the same). Not being able to use XeTeX/LuaTeX is not normal. Try restarting your computer (in case the PATH wasn't loaded correctly), going to Tools > Reconfigure, and the exiting and opening LyX again. First start with a simple document (the default of File > New) and enter some text in English. When you go to File > Export do you see entries for PDF (LuaTeX) and PDF (XeTeX)? Can you export with them? If yes, then go and see if the "use non-Tex fonts (via XeTeX\LuaTex)" is clickable.

Comment: @scottkosty: Doesn't Debian have the last available version of ivritex? 1.2.1? (Not that I'm sure there's much of a difference).

Comment: @einpoklum I thought that ivritex was no longer being maintained or packaged and that is why we need to take it from the archive.

Comment: @scottkosty: Why not use [the ivritex project latest release download link](https://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/ivritex/ivritex/ivritex-1.2.1/ivritex-1.2.1.tar.gz) at SourceForge? Note that the link behaves differently in a browser and from `wget`, i.e. wget won't get redirections to mirrors etc.

Comment: @einpoklum that seems like a good idea. If the the updated deb link breaks, I might change to the one you recommend. Right now I'm going with the "if it aint broken, don't fix it" philosophy.

Answer (score 0):

As your first option, try following @scottkosty's [advice](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/149992/5640); but failing that, you can also try my similar [workaround solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/113431/5640) to this (also similar) problem:

[How do I add Hebrew support to TeXLive on Windows (with pdfTeX+babel)?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/113367/5640)