# Insert hebrew at math-mode (LyX)

Tags: math-mode, lyx, hebrew

I'd like to insert some Hebrew words at math-mode at LyX, like can I inset `\text` or something like that...

There is a way to do this?
Even not at `\text` and by adding special characters (or things that similar to this).

There is any way to do this, or it's impossible?

I saw this:
[What are TeX codes for Hebrew letters to be used as math-mode symbols?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/226793/what-are-tex-codes-for-hebrew-letters-to-be-used-as-math-mode-symbols)
But I'm using LyX (and I don't know how to insert it to LyX), and I want to use all the Hebrew characters....

Thank you!

Comment: This is work for me but I wonder if there is a way that is more simple...  -  http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/148961/hebrew-letters-in-a-math-equation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you [setup your document to use XeTeX](https://www.guyrutenberg.com/2015/03/21/creating-a-hebrew-document-in-lyx-2-1-with-xetex/), it works just as it should: You write `\text` then in the little box you enter your text in Hebrew as is. The only caveat is that LyX will display the text in the formula reversed, but in the output it is fine.

Answer (score -2):

Create a math box inside a math box and type: "\R{hebrew text}"

```
\documentclass[english,hebrew]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9,cp1255]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amstext}
\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
   \L{$\text{\R{\text{עברית}}}$}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This doesn't work...

Comment: well for me its does

Comment: You should then add more detail. Do you have a special module or package that you include allowing your text to be set in Hebrew via `\R`?

Comment: I guess you gotta have the miktex and the hebrew fonts (culmus). Nothing other than that

Comment: What does `\R` do?

Comment: I dunno, i just read it somewhere and it worked

Comment: ...well, we like to use definitive, fact-based answers here.

Comment: well this method works for me, i don't know how to explain it better than that. as simple as that

Comment: And I really cant understand your approach, why would I post something if I cant stand behind it? Did you even try it for yourself? I mean, it does work for me and probably would work for others, why else would I post it? Moreover, It took me several hours to find this solution in the internet and now you are voting to delete it? I really hope someone would find it helpful as long as it stays here. I thought the idea of Q&A is to have some answers in it.

Comment: I opened up LyX, inserted an (inline) math box, typed `\R{hebrew text}` and compiled. I received an undefined control sequence error as a result of `\R`. I can't retract my vote-to-delete, but has flagged this for moderator attention to convert it to a comment. If you can provide some detail that would help people like me make this work, then that would be awesome.

Comment: What kind of detail?

Comment: Go through your Document > Settings... > LaTeX Preamble and/or Modules and figure out what you have in your setup that might allow you to do this. Look at your `.log` file. Figure it out and support the community by adding some comprehensive detail.

Comment: No Preamble nor Modules are used, all is empty

Comment: \documentclass[english,hebrew]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9,cp1255]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amstext}
\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
\L{$\text{\R{\text{עברית}}}$}
\end{document}

Comment: this is from the Latex Source*

Comment: Under Document > Settings... > Language, you have [these following settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ryzSh.png), correct? Additionally, you've formatting the content within the math box as text, so you don't just use `\R{..}`, but `\text{\R{...}}`? Don't know how you added `\usepackage{amstext}` to the preamble. These are things you need to figure out.

Comment: How doesn't this provide an answer to the question? It says exactly what you have to do in order to write Hebrew text inside math mode