# Inserting Hebrew letters at xymatrix (at LyX)

Tags: xetex, lyx, luatex, xy-pic, hebrew

my previous question was how to insert Hebrew letters (i.e. Hebrew words) to LyX document at **math mode**.
[This answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/281625/29476) helps me a lot and now it's perfect (I follow [this post](https://www.guyrutenberg.com/2015/03/21/creating-a-hebrew-document-in-lyx-2-1-with-xetex/)...)
  but....

When I try to insert letters to colored circle at `xymatrix` I get a black square :-(

Do you know how to solve it? or if it's possible...

I'll put here the source of the of the lyx file, but I don't know which format (the default or the XeTeX.

Here is the default:

```
    % Preview source code

%% LyX 2.2.2 created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
\documentclass[a4paper,english,hebrew]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}
\usepackage[all]{xy}

\makeatletter

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% LyX specific LaTeX commands.
\pdfpageheight\paperheight
\pdfpagewidth\paperwidth


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Textclass specific LaTeX commands.
\usepackage{theorem}
\theorembodyfont{\upshape}
\newtheorem{theorem}{\R{משפט}}[section]
\AtBeginDocument{\make@lr\thetheorem}

% The following chunk fixes export with XeTeX.
% It is needed because polyglossia is used by default
% and \make@lr is only defined by babel.
\@ifundefined{make@lr}
{\def\make@lr#1{\begingroup
    \toks@=\expandafter{#1}%
    \edef\x{\endgroup
  \def\noexpand#1{\noexpand\@number{\the\toks@}}}%
  \x}}{\relax}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Script=Hebrew]{David CLM}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfonttt[Script=Hebrew]{Miriam Mono CLM}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfontsf[Script=Hebrew]{Simple CLM}

\makeatother

\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{hebrew}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\begin{document}
\[
\xymatrix{*++[o][F*:blue]{1}}
\]

\end{document}
```

And here is the XeTeX format:

```
% Preview source code

%% LyX 2.2.2 created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
\documentclass[a4paper,english,hebrew]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}
\usepackage[all]{xy}

\makeatletter

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% LyX specific LaTeX commands.
\pdfpageheight\paperheight
\pdfpagewidth\paperwidth


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Textclass specific LaTeX commands.
\usepackage{theorem}
\theorembodyfont{\upshape}
\newtheorem{theorem}{\R{משפט}}[section]
\AtBeginDocument{\make@lr\thetheorem}

% The following chunk fixes export with XeTeX.
% It is needed because polyglossia is used by default
% and \make@lr is only defined by babel.
\@ifundefined{make@lr}
{\def\make@lr#1{\begingroup
    \toks@=\expandafter{#1}%
    \edef\x{\endgroup
  \def\noexpand#1{\noexpand\@number{\the\toks@}}}%
  \x}}{\relax}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Script=Hebrew]{David CLM}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfonttt[Script=Hebrew]{Miriam Mono CLM}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfontsf[Script=Hebrew]{Simple CLM}

\makeatother

\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{hebrew}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\begin{document}
\[
\xymatrix{*++[o][F*:blue]{1}}
\]

\end{document}
```

Thank you!!

P.S. I mark this box because otherwise it's doesn't work:
[image]

---

Edit:
After [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/345451/29476) it's still don't work. I put the code here:

```
% Preview source code

%% LyX 2.2.2 created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}

\makeatletter

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% LyX specific LaTeX commands.
\pdfpageheight\paperheight
\pdfpagewidth\paperwidth


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Textclass specific LaTeX commands.
\usepackage{theorem}
\theorembodyfont{\upshape}
\newtheorem{theorem}{\R{משפט}}[section]
\AtBeginDocument{\make@lr\thetheorem}

% The following chunk fixes export with XeTeX.
% It is needed because polyglossia is used by default
% and \make@lr is only defined by babel.
\@ifundefined{make@lr}
{\def\make@lr#1{\begingroup
    \toks@=\expandafter{#1}%
    \edef\x{\endgroup
  \def\noexpand#1{\noexpand\@number{\the\toks@}}}%
  \x}}{\relax}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Script=Hebrew]{David CLM}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfonttt[Script=Hebrew]{Miriam Mono CLM}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfontsf[Script=Hebrew]{Simple CLM}
\usepackage[all,pdf]{xy}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\makeatother

\usepackage{xunicode}
\begin{document}
\L{
\[
\xymatrix{*++[o][F*:blue]{a}}
\]
}
\end{document}
```

---

Here is the LyX file:

```
#LyX 2.2 created this file. For more info see http://www.lyx.org/
\lyxformat 508
\begin_document
\begin_header
\save_transient_properties true
\origin unavailable
\textclass heb-article
\begin_preamble
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Script=Hebrew]{David CLM}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfonttt[Script=Hebrew]{Miriam Mono CLM}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfontsf[Script=Hebrew]{Simple CLM}
\usepackage[all,pdf]{xy}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\end_preamble
\use_default_options true
\maintain_unincluded_children false
\language hebrew
\language_package none
\inputencoding cp1255
\fontencoding global
\font_roman "default" "default"
\font_sans "default" "default"
\font_typewriter "default" "default"
\font_math "auto" "auto"
\font_default_family default
\use_non_tex_fonts true
\font_sc false
\font_osf false
\font_sf_scale 100 100
\font_tt_scale 100 100
\graphics default
\default_output_format default
\output_sync 0
\bibtex_command default
\index_command default
\paperfontsize default
\spacing single
\use_hyperref false
\papersize a4paper
\use_geometry false
\use_package amsmath 1
\use_package amssymb 1
\use_package cancel 1
\use_package esint 1
\use_package mathdots 1
\use_package mathtools 1
\use_package mhchem 1
\use_package stackrel 1
\use_package stmaryrd 1
\use_package undertilde 1
\cite_engine basic
\cite_engine_type default
\biblio_style plain
\use_bibtopic false
\use_indices false
\paperorientation portrait
\suppress_date false
\justification true
\use_refstyle 1
\index Index
\shortcut idx
\color #008000
\end_index
\secnumdepth 3
\tocdepth 3
\paragraph_separation indent
\paragraph_indentation 0cm
\quotes_language english
\papercolumns 1
\papersides 1
\paperpagestyle default
\tracking_changes false
\output_changes false
\html_math_output 0
\html_css_as_file 0
\html_be_strict false
\end_header

\begin_body

\begin_layout Standard
\begin_inset Formula 
\[
\xymatrix{*++[o][F*:blue]{a}}
\]

\end_inset


\end_layout

\end_body
\end_document
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) Your two documents are the same. They are both for XeTeX.

(2) This problem has noting to do with Hebrew. There is not Hebrew in the `xymatrix`. The black box is placed there because the `[F*:blue]` doesn't work. That should be in the XeTeX error messages.

To get it working you have to change this in the pramble:

Replace

```
\usepackage[all]{xy}
```

with

```
\usepackage[all,pdf]{xy}
\usepackage{xcolor}
```

Here is a preamble for the document (`Document > Settings > LaTeX Preamble`)

```
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\xyoption{pdf}
\usepackage{xcolor}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% LyX specific LaTeX commands.
\pdfpageheight\paperheight
\pdfpagewidth\paperwidth


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Textclass specific LaTeX commands.
\usepackage{theorem}
\theorembodyfont{\upshape}
\newtheorem{theorem}{\R{משפט}}[section]
\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{\make@lr\thetheorem}

% The following chunk fixes export with XeTeX.
% It is needed because polyglossia is used by default
% and \make@lr is only defined by babel.
\@ifundefined{make@lr}{\def\make@lr#1{\begingroup
    \toks@=\expandafter{#1}%
    \edef\x{\endgroup
  \def\noexpand#1{\noexpand\@number{\the\toks@}}}%
  \x}}{\relax}
\makeatother

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Script=Hebrew]{David CLM}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfonttt[Script=Hebrew]{Miriam Mono CLM}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfontsf[Script=Hebrew]{Simple CLM}

\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
```

Comment: Doesn't work :-(  Here is the errors I get: http://imgur.com/a/iDscy

Comment: I change few things at your suggestions (I did few tries, each time I changed something else) - but it's still doesn't work...

Comment: Apparently you typed `\usepackage[all,pdf][xy]` instead of `\usepackage[all,pdf]{xy}`. Copy/paste is easier :)

Comment: No, I copy as you wrote (from your answer) and it's still not working... :-(

Comment: I put the code after your suggestion (look at the edited question) this still not working...

Comment: You didn't do what I said. You added my code. I said that you should replace the original `\usepackage`. If you do that it will work. So in your revised program I have now removed `\usepackage[all]{xy}` and then it should work. And please, don't ignore the error messages that `xetex` gives you. If you had looked there, you would have seen it.

Comment: I try, but LyX put it... How do I remove it from LyX? It put it automatically..

Comment: @Yoar can you post a minimal example .lyx file? It is just a text file so you can paste it in your question like code. Then ping me and I can take a look.

Comment: It seems LyX is a bit nasty. I'll put the LaTeX preamble for LyX in my answer. However, there is one problem when I do this with LyX: LyX insert `\L` before the diagram (apparently to get left-to-right text), but \L is defined as the slashed L (from Polish) instead of left-to-right. So something is missing.

Comment: @scottkosty - I put the `.lyx` file...

Comment: @PietvanOostrum - It's still not working - it's compiling but I can't type Hebrew letters (inside)... :-(

Comment: @Yoar in your .lyx file, just go to Document > Settings > Local Layout and put "Provides xy 1", then "Validate", then "OK". This tells LyX that you will handle the loading of the xy package in the user preamble.

Comment: Thank you so much! It's working!!   BTW, the XeTeX should work fine, right? Thanks!!

Comment: @Yoar not sure what you mean but yes XeTeX is good to use with Hebrew from what I understand.